# Selecting the best available option using BASH

Tags: bash, command-line, conditional-statements

I curious as whether a shell script to pick the best available option from a list of options can be written in a neater way than this?

```
d="least wanted directory"
dt="possible directory"    && [ -d $dt ] && d=$dt
dt="preferred directory"   && [ -d $dt ] && d=$dt
```

Comment: Oh, someone here can usually think of something extra clever, so let's wait and see what that is.  However, I think that your way is neat.

Comment: I can also make a loop of it: `for dt in "least wanted" possible preferred; do [ -d $dt ] && d=$dt; done`

Comment: Or `for dt in preferred possible "least wanted"; do [ -d $dt ] && d=$dt && break; done`

Answer (score 1):

Readable version (efficient thanks to @CodeGnome):

```
dirs=("preferred directory" "possible directory" "least wanted directory")

for test_dir in "${dirs[@]}"
do
    if [ -d "$test_dir" ]
    then
        dir="$test_dir"
        break
    fi
done
echo "$dir"
```

Comment: If you reverse the order of the directories so that preferred is first, you can short-circuit the loop with `break` after assigning to *dir* and save a couple of iterations.

Comment: `for test_dir in "preferred directory" "possible directory" "least wanted directory"; do test -d "$test_dir" || continue; dir=$test_dir; break; done`

Comment: Sure, but I prefer to use a variable and as few "goto"-style statements as possible. You could post it as a separate answer.